# Why synchronizing on the field variable and incrementing it inside synchronized block results in print out of order?

Tags: java, multithreading, concurrency, synchronized

I have a simple code snippet

```
public class ItemManager {

    private Integer itemCount = 0;

    public void incrementAndPrint() {
        synchronized(this) { 
            System.out.println(++itemCount + " ");
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ItemManager manager = new ItemManager();
        ExecutorService executor = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(20);

        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
            executor.submit(manager::incrementAndPrint); 
        }
        executor.shutdown();
    }
}
```

that produces 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 as expected. I can also create another field with Object instance and lock on it

```
    private Integer itemCount = 0;
    private Object lock = new Object();

    public void incrementAndPrint() {
        synchronized(lock) {
            System.out.println(++itemCount + " ");
        }
    }
```

and it will also produce 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 as expected.

However, if I try to lock on the same object that I want to increment and print

```
    private Integer itemCount = 0;

    public void incrementAndPrint() {
        synchronized(itemCount) {
            System.out.println(++itemCount + " ");
        }
    }
```

the operation will stay atomic but the result is out of order: 2 1 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10.

I know that `synchronized(this)` or synchronizing the whole method will fix all my problems. I just can't understand why I can lock on one field (`Object lock`), but can't lock on another (`Integer itemCount`)? Shouldn't everything inside the `synchronized` block be locked properly, regardless of what this object is, as long as it is a single object shared between all threads?

Comment: You do _not_ want to synchronize on an Object that might be cached, like `Integer`. Never do that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`Integer`s in Java are immutable. When you call `++itemCount`, you're in fact performing three operations: First, the `Integer` is unboxed to an `int` with the value of `Integer`. Then, this primitive `int` is incremented, and finally the incremented `int` is autoboxed back to an `Integer`. So in fact, you eventually have **different** `Integer` instances. Since you synchronize on different instances, the synchronization is meaningless, and you see the out-of-order printing.

Comment: Mureinik, I see, so it basically creates several instances of Integer. Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

Because when you do `++itemCount`, it is equivalent to:

```
int old = itemCount.intValue();
itemCount = Integer.valueOf(old + 1);
```

This changes the object that the lock is using, hence the synchronization is no longer correct. This happens for primitive wrapper classes like `Integer` and `Long`.

You can see the difference if you replace the `Integer` with an `AtomicInteger` which can increment the same object:

```
private AtomicInteger itemCount = new AtomicInteger();

public void incrementAndPrint() {
    synchronized(itemCount) { 
        System.out.println(itemCount.getAndIncrement() + " ");
    }
}
```